# How can I check the validity of a form using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

I had a previous question about how to check submit it was answered like this:

```
$("form").on("submit", function() {
    var $form = $(this);

    // if there are validation errors do not continue.
    if (!$form.valid()) {
        return false;
    }
});​
```

However in VS2012 it shows .valid as "this property does not exist on value of type jQuery". Note that I didn't try to run it yet as I still see the syntax error in VS2012 editor.

In my script directory I have the following **_reference.js** file. Should I be telling VS2012 about this or referencing it in my script or something?

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.8.3.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
```

Can someone give me some advice on what is wrong?

**Solution**

I had a _reference.js file but to make this work okay I had to include a reference to the _reference.js file in my script. Now it works okay.

Comment: Are you using jQuery.validate plugin or HTML5 validation?

Comment: jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.valid)

Comment: @Jonathan - What do you mean by your comment?

Comment: that snippet will return whether the method `valid` exists for `jquery`

Comment: My page loads the jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive scripts. Is this just a problem with syntax checks not knowing about these?

Comment: @fabricio - I am using jQuery validation.

Comment: @SamanthaJ: Yeah... it may be. Try to run it ignoring the warning/error.

Comment: @Jonathan - Hi but how can I make it not give a syntax error in VS2012 ?

Comment: The [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) method is documented and is obviously part of the plugin. Weird how VS doesn't catch it even after including the reference.

Comment: @Farbricio - I am not actually including the reference. I just have the _reference.js file there. However I am not sure how to use that. Should I refer to the _reference.js file in every script ?

Comment: @Fabrcio - It works now. I included that reference file in my script.

Comment: I haven't used VS for ~2 years so I didn't quite remember how to include the references, you can submit an answer to don't leave this unanswered. `=]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `validate()` before calling `valid()`

```
$("form").validate();
$("form").on("submit", function() {
    var $form = $(this);

    // if there are validation errors do not continue.
    if (!$form.valid()) {
        return false;
    }
});​
```

Comment: @Palesh - Does the validate not get called automatically with the submit? If not then thanks for that good point of yours. What I also want to find out is why do I get the syntax error in VS2012 editor saying .valid does not exist?

Comment: Are you using the latest validate plugin?

Comment: Yes I am. /*! jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.10.0 - 9/7/2012